# Batch file. Open a set of Crome tabs in a new window

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, batch

I have the following batch file that opens a set of few tabs in separate Crome window for the specified profile.

```
@echo off

start chrome --new-window --profile-directory="Default" "https://stackoverflow.com/" "https://www.youtube.com/"

exit
```

It works fine, when I already have another window of the same profile opened. However, when I try launch it with no Chrome windows previously opened, it opens the desired tabs AND all tabs from the previous profile session in one window.

**How can I avoid this without changing the lauch preferences in profile?**

To be clear, I want these links "https://stackoverflow.com/" "https://www.youtube.com/" always to be opened in a separate Chrome window after launching .bat file, no matter what.

Besides, I want to keep the main settings in this profile unchanged, so I can always open the last session tabs without these links "https://stackoverflow.com/" "https://www.youtube.com/".

Answer (score 0):

ok I have revised my answer to better reflect what you are asking for. For this solution you will need to have [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) installed. Once installed create a script with the following:

```
IfWinExist, ahk_exe Chrome.exe
{
    run, Chrome.exe --new-window https://stackoverflow.com www.youtube.com
    return
}
else
{
    run, Chrome.exe
    return
}
```

To make a script simply open a file in notepad and save, then rename the extension to `.ahk`.
Next, create a shortcut to your script and place it wherever you like.

## What this script does

What this does is check to see if Chrome is already running. If it **IS** running, then it will launch the new window with the specified tabs.

If it is **NOT** running it will simply load Chrome normally.

It should be noted though, that if you close your main window (the one with your other tabs, not the YouTube and StackOverflow), **BEFORE** you close the newly opened window, then the next time you open Chrome it might load just the two tabs. This is normal behavior for Chrome to remember the tabs of the last opened (and closed) window.

Comment: Problem is that the set of tabs that is opened together with the desired tabs is not fixed, they are the tabs from the last session. So the proposed solution for this caveat does not work in this case.

Comment: could you not modify this script then to close all currently opened tabs, wait, then launch the rest of the script?

Comment: I've added taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul , then wait, then open desired tabs. Partly it works fine, now always new window with "https://stackoverflow.com/" and "https://www.youtube.com/" opens. But the tabs from previous sessions are lost. Please, if you meant something else, elaborate more.

Comment: Well, for me the script from the answer as is does not launch listed tabs in a new window. It do so when I added taskkill, but then the tabs from the previous session are lost. Sorry, it looks like I can not get what you mean. Could you, please, provide the code?

Comment: @АндрейКокорев Ok I have completely reworked the answer to something I think will work for what you are asking.